# Will Google Analytics show "google / organic" source correctly if a redirection happens in between?

Tags: google-analytics

To be specific, when a user visit the target website homepage `A` through Google search:

> It will show "**google / organic**" as source

But if a redirection rule is created from `A` to `B`:

> Will it still be "google / organic"? or become "**direct**"?

Comment: While redirects will preserve the referrer (on which "Google/organic" is based), they won't always preserve URL parameters.   Some GA sources (like advertising campaigns) are based on "UTM" parameters.  The answer for those would be different than the answer about Google referrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how the redirect is done. The source / medium is derived intelligently from the HTTP referrer header.

Generally:

- A server side redirect will preserve the original referrer. A 30x redirect therefore will preserve the 'source / medium'.
- A client-side redirect using meta refresh or javascript will remove the referrer. This will mean it appears as 'direct' as the header has been stripped.

There are bound to be exceptions to these with different clients/servers. There are actions that can cause this header to be stripped or modified. Some sites will do this on purpose in order to mask the origin. Facebook is an example, where it will redirect external URLs in order to strip out the exact origin.